# Remove warning on my answer.

Tags: support

uh some overactive moderator put a notice on my answer here cause i disagreed with chris and some other guy would you remove it i plainly cite the genetic changes

[Why is the current Ebola outbreak different from previous outbreaks?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/why-is-the-current-ebola-outbreak-different-from-previous-outbreaks/21000#21000)

Answer (score 4):

I've removed it again, you could have avoided this by actually quoting the relevant part of the article.

Your answer is still somewhat misleading as the article states that they don't know if the severity of the outbreak is associated with those mutations, but that is something for the community to decide.

Comment: citation included from original article as requested.